# highcharts-react-official rendering issue with React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I've just implemented [highcharts-react-official](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) (1.1.0) as a stateless React (16.0.0) component.

'chartData' is rendered using the state of the parent App which can change depending on the report, but when my HighchartsWrapper componenet is rendering, it seems to ignore changes to 'chartData' and doesn't render the correct (latest) data. Other config data passed as props are applied (chart type for example) When I `console.log(props.chartData)`, I can see that the data is correct. The 'chartData' changes that don't render are usually ones where the number of series on the graph change.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

const HighchartsWrapper = (props) => {
   console.log(props.chartData); // this is always correct

    let options = {
        title: { text: 'My chart' },
        series: props.chartData
    }

    return(
            <HighchartsReact
                highcharts={Highcharts}
                options={options}
            />
    );
}

export default HighchartsWrapper;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return` not `render`?

Comment: @Colin edited - thanks. A mistake in the example/simplified code for the post, but my real component uses render.

Comment: I have made a live example with your component and updating props in the chart component updates the chart - see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9tajgc?file=index.js. Can you adjust the live example to show the issue?

Comment: here's the update @morganfree - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eli4k8?file=index.js The issue is seen when trying to add new series to the chart. The data for this particular chart is being source from various network devices, so latency will be different, and results will come in a different times.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is fixed by new wrapper release. The problem occurs because there wasn't  possibility in the wrapper to manually set the `oneToOne` parameter of `Chart.update()` function. Now you can simply set the `oneToOne={true}` as component props. Then it works correctly.

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yctlyw?file=Chart.js

Best regards!

Comment: We discussed it a bit more, so in a few days, there will be no need to set the `oneToOne` anymore, because it will be set to `true` by default.